# Use of INDIRECT for multiple graph regions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have used `INDIRECT` and `OFFSET` to dynamically update graphs in Excel. I have not been able to find a solution to this problem when the graph region consists of multiple ranges. Below is an example of a graph reference to multiple ranges:

1. In the graph dialog:

   ```
   (Sheet1!$G$2:$G$22,Sheet1!$H$2:$H$22,Sheeet1!$I$2:$I$22)
   ```

   [Some people call the `,` the concatenation of ranges.]
2. In the formula bar:

   ```
   =SERIES(,(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$22,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$22,Sheeet1!$C$2:$C$22),
            (Sheet1!$G$2:$G$22,Sheet1!$H$2:$H$22,Sheeet1!$I$2:$I$22),1)
   ```

Using `INDIRECT` when only having a single range works fine (the technique has been illustrated many times on SO), but it fails when using ranges such as the ones above (invalid reference).

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to this problem.
I used the **INDIRECT()** function for the entire expression `(Sheet1!$G$2:$G$22, Sheet1!$H$2:$H$22, Sheet1!$I$2:$I$22)`. So if the above expression is present as string in let's say **A1** of **Sheet1** then I defined the named variable `YVALUES  = INDIRECT(Sheet1!$A$1)`.

In the graph dialog I selected for the **y values : Sheet1!YVALUES** which results in an error.The solution is to define three named variables, one for each region. Assume that A1 contains the string Sheet1!$G$2:$G$22, A2 the string `Sheet1!$H$2:$H$22`, and **A3** the string `Sheet1!$I$2:$I$22`.

Now define the named variables `YVAL1 = INDIRECT (Sheet1!$A$1), YVAL2 = INDIRECT (Sheet1!$A$1), and YVAL3 = INDIRECT (Sheet1!$A$3)`.

In the graph dialog I enter `(Sheet1!YVAL1, Sheet1!YVAL2, Sheet1!YVAL3)`.  This works, it is important to remember to type in the brackets and commas in the graph dialog box.